# Dynamic Generic Sobject multiple instances

Tags: apex, visualforce, trigger, community

I have a list of sobject and I am trying to add Account,Contact and Oppty records on runtime it's working fine.But how can I achieve it dynamically using sobjects type and describe methods i.e more dynamic without dependency.

```
public List<sObject> records;
records.add(new Account(Rating='Hot'));
records.add(new Contact(LastName='George'));
records.add(new Opportunity(Stage='Closed Won'));
insert records;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with help of describe call as below:

```
sObject sObj = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('<SobjectName>').newSObject();
```

Now you can put fields value dynamically:

```
sobj.put('Name', 'Test');
```

After that you can add to list and perform DML operation.

Comment: Thank you, so far I achieved this .I want to do it in a sobject list String sObjectName = 'Account';
Schema.SObjectType t  = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName);
SObject s = t.newSObject();
s.put('Name','test');
insert s;

Comment: Your code is not readable....are you getting any issue ...? or you want to initialize in array?

Comment: String sObjectName = 'Account';
Schema.SObjectType t  = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(sObjectName);
SObject s = t.newSObject();
s.put('Name','test');
insert s;

Comment: Thanks for help.I want to set record based on external Id in the put method and use sObject list

Comment: do you want to perform upsert of list based on external id?

Comment: I have three objects as Account,Contact and Opp for example..I have externail Id on account based on that i wan't to populate account on contact and opp and then insert it as sobject list.

Answer (score 0):

A related point is to take care how you order the types within the `List<sObject>` as otherwise, it is easy to run into this exception:

```
System.TypeException: Cannot have more than 10 chunks in a single operation.
```

Put all the SObjects of the same type adjacent to each other: if they are intermingled the type can change more than 10 times through the list.

This also means that no more than 10 types can be updated in a single DML call.